# ASP.NET Session Cookies - specifying the base domain

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

By default, ASP.NET will set its cookies to use "mydomain.com" as their base.  I'd prefer to have them use "www.mydomain.com" instead, so that I can have other "sub.mydomain.com" subdomains that are cookie-free.

I've done some digging into the Session and Cookie objects, and while I can find how to set the domain for a single cookie, I don't see a way to set it for all Session cookies.

Anybody ideas?

Comment: This is the exact opposite of my experience. New session cookies are being created one each of my subdomains. Perhaps it's changed with a newer version of ASP.NET? I'm use .NET 4.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Create a [ISessionIDManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.isessionidmanager.aspx), since you only want to change the cookie domain we will let the default one do all the work.

This is configured in web.config on the sessionState element under `<system.web>`.

```
<sessionState sessionIDManagerType="MySessionIDManager" />
```

And the implementation.

```
public class MySessionIDManager: SessionIDManager, ISessionIDManager
{   
    void ISessionIDManager.SaveSessionID( HttpContext context, string id, out bool redirected, out bool cookieAdded )
    {
        base.SaveSessionID( context, id, out redirected, out cookieAdded );

        if (cookieAdded) {
            var name = "ASP.NET_SessionId";
            var cookie = context.Response.Cookies[ name ];
            cookie.Domain = "example.com";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks really great, but it did not worked for me. THis code was able to maintain same sessionid for all subdomains, but data of sessions wasn't read successfully.

Comment: Worked great for me!  Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you also handle the `GetSessionId()` and `RemoveSessionId()` ???

Comment: OK. Looking at the code of `SessionIDManager` it seems that this is not needed. :)

Comment: This solutions works perfectly fine for me locally. But when I host my app on IIS, application is failing to log-in. Can you suggest me the reason behind this issue?

Answer (score 13):

I realise this is an old question, but could you use the `domain` attribute of the [httpCookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228262(v=vs.100).aspx) configuration section instead of doing this in code?

```
<httpCookies domain="String" 
             httpOnlyCookies="true|false" 
             requireSSL="true|false" />
```

Comment: does not seem to have an effect on session cookie

Comment: +1 This worked for me! It affected both session and auth cookies.

Comment: Tested in .Net 4, 4.5, 4.6.1 - worked for me, a much simpler solution than the accepted answer.

Comment: Works for me :)

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. It's framework version dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Session uses only one cookie, so why don't you set domain only for ASP.NET_SessionId cookie ?

Comment: 5, actually, if you include the _utm... ones.  All of those get sent across for every image request to cdn.mysite.com.  It would be nice if I didn't need to go out and register mysitecdn.com just to avoid that.

Comment: Registering a "cookieless domain" is not so uncommon: [SO did this for example](http://sstatic.net/).