# Store Session cookie for groups of subdomains in ASP.NET IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies, web-config

I have an application running ASP.NET.   I have different domains and different sub-domains. I want the domains to share session with their sub domains.

For Example, the following domains access this application: 
www.example1.com
print.example1.com
www.example2.com
print.example2.com

If a user goes to www.example1.com and print.example1.com, I want it to use the same session. If the user were to go to www.example2.com and print.example2.com, I would want it to use a different session than the *.example1.com.

The way I used to handle it was a hack in page_load that works perfectly in IIS6:
         Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = Session.SessionID;
        Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Domain = SiteUtility.GetCookieDomain();
        (SiteUtility.GetCookieDomain would return .example1.com or .example2.com depending on the url of the request)

Unfortunately, this no longer seems to work for iis7. Each subdomain/domain a user goes to, the user gets a new session cookie.

I then found the web.config entry: 
'<httpCookies domain=".example1.com" />.

This works great for sharing session cookie between example1.com subdomains. Unfortunately, this completely screws up session state for *.example2.com.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: Thanks all for your help.  I determined that one of the subdomains was in a trusted state in ie8 while the other was not.  When both are in a trusted state (and presumambly both in an untrusted state) it works.  Pauli spent the most time with me on this, so i want to give him the credit for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a `HttpModule` that intercepts the `EndRequest`-event, iterates over the `Response.Cookies` collection, finds the session-cooke and changes its `Domain` property before actually sending it to the client.

**Edit:**

Kevin at the end determined that one of the subdomains was in a trusted state in ie8 while the other was not. When both are in a trusted state (and presumambly both in an untrusted state) it works. I did spent the most time on this, so Kevin want to give me the credit for the answer.

Comment: How would I be sure the cookie would be read at the beginrequest?  Would I want to create a second httpModule that iterates the request?  (reading up on httpmodules...)

Comment: You shouldn't need to care about BeginRequest... all you need to do is to make sure the cookies sent to the client has the correct domains set, no? To your question though, you can instruct a single module to respond to all the events you need.

Comment: I created my httpmodule and it is being called correctly.  Unfortunately, it is still not working cross domain.  The odd thing is, the hack i have above works perfectly in iis6.

Comment: what does fiddler say, what is the actual content of the cookies sent from the server?

Comment: Set-Cookie: MyCustomCookie=xt35oxia3mfvmzehz0r0v445; domain=.example1.com; expires=Thu, 06-Jan-2011 07:19:06 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly

Comment: Set-Cookie: MyCustomCookie=m2zz4tetin0ll445tc2ed0rb; domain=.example1.com; expires=Thu, 06-Jan-2011 07:20:27 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly

Comment: Now, I changed my session state web.config entry to include:                 cookieName="MyCustomCookie".  Also, this is working in firefox.  I am beginning to suspect this is an ie8 issue and not a iis7 issue.

Comment: sounds plausible :).. so are you saying that the domain property on your cookies are actually set correctly on both of your domains?

Comment: I'm looking into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326521/asp-net-session-cookies-specifying-the-base-domain

Comment: interesting, i didn't know about the ISessionIDManager interface... learned something today as well then :)

Comment: hmm... ok, now i am angry.  I found out what the problem was.  one site was trusted and the other wasn't.  I've been banging my head against the wall for days on this.  Thank you for your help.  How do I give you credit for the answer? This is my first time posting on stackoverflow (use it all the time, though).

Comment: hehe :) that is what happens sometimes, noting else to do than smile and grab a beer! you just upvote my answer, eventually adding one your own as well that you accept.

Comment: crap, i don't have enough reputation to upvote you.  want to copy/paste my comment and i will accept that as the answer?

Comment: Excelent.  now for that beer.

Comment: And Thank you for spending the time with me.  I am always happy to find people willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

rather than using SiteUtility.GetCookieDomain(), try using:

```
var domainSansTLD = Request.Url.Host.Replace(".com", "");
var secondLevelDomain = domainSansTLD.Substring(domainSansTLD.LastIndexOf('.'));
var cookieDomain = secondLevelDomain + ".com";
```

Comment: Pauli is correct that putting this in an HttpModule's EndRequest would be much cleaner than in the page_load

Comment: GetCookieDomain pretty much does this   Wow, that looks terrible...
    public static string GetCookieDomain()
    {

        Uri url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
        string domain = url.DnsSafeHost;
        string[] splitDomain = domain.Split('.');
        int splitCount = splitDomain.Count();

        System.Text.StringBuilder retVal = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i < splitDomain.Count(); i++)
            {
                retVal.AppendFormat(".{0}", splitDomain[i]);
            }

        return retVal.ToString();
    
    }

Answer (score 0):

First way,

Store session as file in a location that both servers can access (this is good for virtual servers or shared folders). This method is a bit unreliable and shared folders and lag thus causing problems.

Okay, I was going to write a couple of other methods but I'm sure they'll be posted as they have more knowledge with asp.net than I, however, I do have a personal preference that I think would be a good option.

This option would be a memcache server. Essentially it's a database that runs off RAM and you point all of your sessions to it (tcp://mem.domain.com:1234 ... sorry I can't remember the usual port off the top of my head).

I hope I was of some help,

Jon