# web.config in .net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, web-config

I developed an app in 4.0 (my 1st time) and I have only 2 pages in it. I deployed it and it is working fine if I type www.mytestapp.com/testpage.aspx

But If I just type mytestapp.com it is redirecting it to www.mytestapp.com/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f

I think it is because I have below lines in my web.config file. But when I comment out these lines and deploy the code

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
```

and if I type www.mytestapp.com/testpage.aspx It is asking me for userid and password.

How can I fix this?? how can I make the app go to testpage.aspx by default without asking for any userid and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is problem with HttpCookie that generated for ASP.net Session and FormAuthentication cookie.
Web.Config Put this

```
 <system.Web>
   <httpCookies domain=".mytestapp.com" />
 </system.web>
```

Comment: It didn't worked. I tried adding this and commenting the <authentication> part (didn't worked) , Adding this and keeping the <authentication> part. (didn't worked either)

Comment: This is first part 
1. Change aspnet_sessionid cookie
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326521/asp-net-session-cookies-specifying-the-base-domain

Comment: Instead of commenting out the code I modified the Loginurl to testpage.aspx

    <authentication mode="Forms"> 
     <forms loginUrl="~/Account/testpage.aspx " timeout="2880" /> 
     </authentication> 

That solved my Issue.