# How to access cookie between Server.com to Client.com

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, cookies

i have read a lot about cookie and i still can’t understand it right

have two domains

```
server: server.com
client: client.com
```

so the website is just deployed and there are many issues, i understand that there isn’t way to share cookie between two domains

> when disable Prevent Cross-Site on Safari it is work fine but
> **probably that is not make sense to ask from each client to disable it...**

my Question is if i can set the `server.com` on
`server.domain.com` and the client on `domain.com`
is possible to share cookie between `server.domain.com(serverSide)` to  `domain.com(clientSide)` ?

or just simply: **"How to use cookies between server domain to client domain In the right way after hosting ?"**

Comment: Cookies that are set for `domain.com`, can be accessed on subdomains thereof, such as `server.domain.com`, yes. But the setting you changed in your Safari is about 3rd-party cookies in general - so you would have to hope that Safari (and other browsers) do not consider `domain.com` and `server.domain.con` as "different parties", otherwise you are winning absolutely nothing with such a change.

Comment: But after short research, https://stackoverflow.com/a/29772014/1427878 seems to confirm that subdomains of the main domain are _not_ considered 3rd-party - so this could make it work, without users having to change default settings in their browsers, yes.

Comment: @CBroe first thanks you for understanding answered, just to be on the same page with you: on server side `server.com ("old domain")` i need to set this domain to `"server.domain.com"` and then i need to set `(client.com ("old domain")` to "domain.com" and then i have get `"server.domain.com/data"` function on server that brings information from some Database, so it’s means now that i can make request function  to `"server.domain.com/data"` from client correctly ?

Comment: That should prevent browsers from blocking the cookie as a 3rd-party cookie, yes. (Which many browser/privacy-enhancing extensions do these days, to prevent user tracking across a whole range of domains.)

Answer (score -1):

the most reliable solution is that the browser that has the cookie set (for example) from `server.com` performs a request with the cookie as a parameter to `client.com` that sets the same cookie on `client.com` website.

Many times a simple (and hidden) `XMLHttpRequest` can do the trick.

Comment: Does that actually get you past the blockage of 3rd-party cookies though? I rather doubt it (because if it did, then all the "bad" guys these blocking measures are against, the track-you-across-half-the-internet data collectors, would surely employ the same tactic.)

Comment: they cannot use the same tactic, because my solution implies a request to a specific endpoint to the second server.

As an example consider the following scenario:   login on ``server.com``, the server sets a cookie,  the browser calls ``client.com/set_this_cookie?cookie=xxx`` and the ``client.com`` domain sets a new cookie with the right value.
You cannot do that if there is no logic on client and server side for this.