# Unable to set path ASP.NET_sessionid cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core

Hi I needed a serious help
i have tried everything but am not able to change the path of **ASP.NET_sessionid** cookie
its path is always set to "/" , i want to set it to a folder or directory

this issue need to be solved as it was raised by app security team
have tried , iis rewrite rule , custom session id manager
any help much aprreciated

Answer (score 2):

As @iamdln said, you need to create your own SessionIDManager but you also need to config it on your Web.config.

It worked for me.

**Your SessionIdManager class**,

```
public class MySessionIDManager : SessionIDManager, ISessionIDManager
{
    void ISessionIDManager.SaveSessionID(HttpContext context, string id, out bool redirected, out bool cookieAdded)
    {
        base.SaveSessionID(context, id, out redirected, out cookieAdded);

        if (cookieAdded)
        {
            var name = "ASP.NET_SessionId";
            var cookie = context.Response.Cookies[name];
            cookie.Path = "/yourPath";
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.config**, replace namespace and class for yours.
This goes inside **<system.web>** section.

```
<sessionState sessionIDManagerType = "Namespace.MySessionIDManager"></sessionState>
```

Original links:

[ASP.NET Forum - Explains how to override path](https://forums.asp.net/t/2154216.aspx?ASP%20NET_SessionId%20Cookie%20override%20the%20path)

[StackOverFlow - Explains how to override domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326521/asp-net-session-cookies-specifying-the-base-domain)

Both are quite similar anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own [SessionIDManager](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/State/SessionIDManager.cs,83825448a3da6ede) which is inherited from ISessionIDManager and change the `cookie.Path` to whatever you want.

```
static HttpCookie CreateSessionCookie(String id) {
    HttpCookie  cookie;

    cookie = new HttpCookie(Config.CookieName, id);
    cookie.Path = "/";
    cookie.SameSite = Config.CookieSameSite;

    // VSWhidbey 414687 Use HttpOnly to prevent client side script manipulation of cookie
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;

    return cookie;
}
```