# Asp.Net Application cookie path setup

Tags: asp.net, setcookie, cookie-path

I have to set a cookie path  attribute in  the asp.net application. I am getting "" only path if I changed the session state .Please help me to how to change cookie path in the asp.net application

//web config

//global asax
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// only apply session cookie persistence to requests requiring session information
if (Context.Handleris IRequiresSessionState || Context.Handleris IReadOnlySessionState)
{
var sessionState = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState")as SessionStateSection;
var cookieName = sessionState !=null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionState.CookieName) ? sessionState.CookieName :"ASP.NET_SessionId";

```
    var timeout = sessionState !=null ? sessionState.Timeout : TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);

    // Ensure ASP.NET Session Cookies are accessible throughout the subdomains.
    if (Request.Cookies[cookieName] !=null && Session !=null && Session.SessionID !=null)
    {
        Response.Cookies[cookieName].Value = Session.SessionID;
        Response.Cookies[cookieName].Path = Request.ApplicationPath;
        Response.Cookies[cookieName].Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(timeout);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you should Provide Default Path for your Cookie which is Server root.
the Below Code snippet shows how to set Default Server Root path

```
 HttpCookie NewCookie = new HttpCookie("ASP.Net_SessionId");
 NewCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
 NewCookie.Secure = false;
 NewCookie.Path = "/";
 NewCookie.Domain = "DomainName";
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(NewCookie);
```

so basically as your Code, you can do Following

```
Response.Cookies[CookieName].Path = "/";
```

Comment: Hi  Vinay,

Path is showing  "/" . But  need to show the custom path .

Comment: umm. 
can you please check this , i hope it will help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69017961/unable-to-set-path-asp-net-sessionid-cookie