# Is it possible to delete cookie in domain from subdomain

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, cookies

Is it possible to delete cookie in http://domain.com from subdomain http://subdomain.domain.com

Comment: This might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444018/sync-cookies-and-sessions-in-different-subdomains-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

You can delete it if the cookie have been set from the domain, or the same subdomain.

When you make a cookie one of the parametres are the domain

```
Response.Cookies["nameof"].Domain
```

If you not set that parameter, then is get the domain that read from url.

If this parameter is with out subdomain `domain.com` then the cookie can be acceded from all subdomains.

If this parameter have subdomain, eg `www.domain.com` then can be acceded only from that one.